# Animated SVG not playing on hard refresh load in Firefox

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, pageload

I've created an animated "loading" SVG. It works fine, except the animation doesn't play on hard refresh (only tested in FF), except when viewing the SVG itself in the browser (not in a document).

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4n8ec4mu/1/)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96" height="96">
 <linearGradient id="a" x1=".5" x2=".5" y2="1">
  <stop stop-color="#191919" offset="0"/>
  <stop stop-color="#999" offset="1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="b" x1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#191919" stop-opacity=".9"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity=".9"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="c" x1="1" x2="0" y1=".5" y2=".5">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#191919" stop-opacity=".8"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity=".8"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="d" x1="1" x2="0" y1="1">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#191919" stop-opacity=".6"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity=".6"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="e" x1=".5" x2=".5" y1="1">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#191919" stop-opacity=".5"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity=".5"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="f" x2="1" y1="1">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#191919" stop-opacity=".4"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity=".4"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="g" x2="1" y1=".5" y2=".5">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#191919" stop-opacity=".3"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity=".3"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="h" x2="1" y2="1">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#191919" stop-opacity=".1"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity=".1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <g>
  <rect width="10" height="25" x="43" y="4" fill="url(#a)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5"/>
  <rect width="25" height="10" x="61.4" y="29.6" fill="url(#b)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5" transform="rotate(-45 61.44 34.56)"/>
  <rect width="25" height="10" x="67" y="43" fill="url(#c)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5"/>
  <rect width="25" height="10" x="61.4" y="56.4" fill="url(#d)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5" transform="rotate(45 61.44 61.44)"/>
  <rect width="10" height="25" x="43" y="67" fill="url(#e)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5"/>
  <rect width="25" height="10" x="9.6" y="56.4" fill="url(#f)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5" transform="rotate(-45 34.56 61.44)"/>
  <rect width="25" height="10" x="4" y="43" fill="url(#g)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5"/>
  <rect width="25" height="10" x="9.6" y="29.6" fill="url(#h)" stroke="#000" ry="5" rx="5" transform="rotate(45 34.56 34.56)"/>
  <animateTransform fill="freeze" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0 48 48" to="360 48 48" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Works well for me in hard refresh in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried it with the Fiddle? The SO snippet doesn't reproduce the problem because it isn't rendered through CSS.
Possibly loading it as a background is the issue?

Comment: works in the Fiddle and in the SO code snippet!

Comment: it only happens when it's loaded exclusively through CSS. As soon as I add an <img> with the SVG as the source it works properly.
I will post an answer.

Comment: Should be fixed in Firefox 51

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you, added that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it might be a Firefox bug (or intended behaviour?), but it seems that the animation isn't started on a hard refresh when the SVG is loaded exclusively through CSS.

Loading it in an IMG tag works fine (and also gets the CSS background to animate properly), so as a workaround I can put a hidden `<img>` somewhere on the page.

The problem might be on my end to begin with though. @Dez reports that it loads properly on his end.

@RobertLongson says that this should be fixed in Firefox 51.